# Adjust longtables to textwidth

Tags: longtable, rowcolor

I would like to adjust my longtables in a document to the textwidth. What would be the best way to go about this?

The code I'm currently using is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{luatextra} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\textwidth = 400pt

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{longtable}[h]{|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{4cm}|p{6cm}|}
\rowcolor{white}\caption{Universal PCR - master reaction mix\label{table:Table8}}
                \hline
                \rowcolor{blue}\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{Universal PCR} & \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{PCR Mix}  & \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{AR 1} &\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{Taq DNA polymerase}\\
                \hline
                \endhead
                11 & 110 µl & 63.25 µl & 2.75 µl\\
                \hline
                25 & 250 µl & 143.75 µl & 6.25 µl\\
                \hline              
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use ltxtable.sty although spreading out numeric columns to text width just makes them harder to read.

Comment: longtable has no `h` option

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Looking at the picture I would say "spreading out" is not the problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer perhaps:-)

Comment: Will I still be able to use the first header color with ltxtable.sty? Also, some tables in my document have \multicolumn . From what I read in the documentation package this is not favorable?

Comment: You can use `ltablex` and its `X` columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the widths, taking account of the rules and column padding
and then choosing the proportion of the remaining width to allocate to each column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{luatextra} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\textwidth = 400pt
\newlength\mylength

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\setlength\mylength{\dimexpr\textwidth-5\arrayrulewidth-8\tabcolsep}
\begin{longtable}{|p{.3\mylength}|p{.2\mylength}|p{.25\mylength}|p{.25\mylength}|}
\rowcolor{white}\caption{Universal PCR - master reaction mix\label{table:Table8}}\\
                \hline
                \rowcolor{blue}\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{Universal PCR} & \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{PCR Mix}  & \textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{AR 1} &\textcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}{Taq DNA polymerase}\\
                \hline
                \endhead
                11 & 110 µl & 63.25 µl & 2.75 µl\\
                \hline
                25 & 250 µl & 143.75 µl & 6.25 µl\\
                \hline              
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, David. This provides the output as required! However, how do I go about the calculcations of my other tables, e.g. tables with only 3 columns or 2? I see you used \textwidth-5\arrayrulewidth-8. How do I re-calculate the values? Sorry for the basic questions.

Comment: @BenneB each column has tabcolsep space each side so that's 8\tabcolsep here (twice number of columns) and you have 5 vertical rules so that's 5\ararayrulewidth